# Point maven settings file to refer from \.m3\settings.xml instead of \.m2\settings.xml

Tags: maven

I am upgrading from maven 2 to maven 3. I have changed the maven home from M2_HOME to M3_HOME, created .m3 folder put the settings.xml inside it. Removed the .m2 folder also.

I see in the maven 3 global settings.xml, the default location of settings.xml is .m2\settings.xml. I could force maven to read the settings.xml from inside .m3 folder by supplying

```
 mvn clean install -Dmaven.repo.local=C:/Users/tabeme/.m3/repository --settings C:\Users\tabeme\.m3\settings.xml
```

But I dont want to do this every time I build. Is there a way I can permanently make maven to read settings.xml from .m3 folder?

Comment: what makes you think you needed to change anything?

Comment: just thought it would be clear to have everything as m3

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147095/191131

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven 3 is a drop in replacement for maven 2.

It uses M2_HOME and .m2 folders as normal.

You should only change settings if you for some reason want to run multiple maven instances.